# Default Comos Db Metrics in Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, collections, azure-cosmosdb, azure-monitoring

I was trying to configure the default cosmos db metrics on azure monitor to get requests, throughputs, and other related info. as given in documentation.
One issue I found was that if I have a collection by the name of **test** in my database in cosmos db account , I sometimes see two collections in Azure monitor under my database that are **Test** and **test**.
But this is kind of intermittent and if I change the time range it sometimes start showing one collection only. I have checked there is no collection by the name of "Test" (with capital T) in my database.
And also the results provided are actually distributed within the two metrics.

Could not find anything on documentation regarding the same.
Is this something on azure's side or something wrong with any configuration?

[image]
(screenshot for the same.)

Comment: Could you please share your log query?

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza
I am using default metrics provided by Monitor for cosmos Db.
It uses following metrics
**"metrics":[{"namespace":"microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts","metric":"microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts-Requests-TotalRequests","aggregation":7,"splitBy":"CollectionName","splitBySortOrder":-1,"splitByLimit":5},]**

Comment: I see the same behavior. I've assumed it's a bug with Azure Monitor, probably needs to be raised with MS support.

Comment: yup, i added one for the same - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/default-comos-db-metrics-in-azure-monitor/m-p/2204830/highlight/true#M3525